# How do i make a button that gets value from a server respond quicker to users?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I am building a social networking application with flutter and Node.js. I used a socket io for real-time connections but for example, when a user clicks on the like a button, there is a little wait time after pressing. is there a trick I can do on the frontend to make it respond to user first then process in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Just play the animation immediately after the user presses the button and send the request to your server in background. If the request failed — you could probably use a toast with an error message, and "retrack" the local like.

Comment: i thought about that but the number of likes still takes some time to change.